# PDF document Icons missing in XSLT webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, xslt, file-icons

In one of the page in where i've XSLT webpart which will populate the documents from the library and show it in table format. Now the issue here is , the icons of the document are not populating especially the PDF icons. This is started when we replace a new WFE server in the farm. In my analysis i found that the image source is

> /_layouts/15/images/icpdf.gif ,

and when i checked my new server there is no folder named 15, it contains only 14 and 16. so i had manually added the 15 folder and its contents in the new server.

[image]

I thought this will fix the issue but the icons are still  not loading in the page. In network traces it shows **status code 404**

What am i missing ? why the icons are not loading, what i should do to make them available in the page. can anyone please help me to fix this.

Comment: You can take a look into this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40873/file-icons-are-not-showing-up). However, I'm concerned, maybe the new WFE was not added properly to the farm. Are you seeing any other issues? Are pages being loaded successfully from the new WFE server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint server 2016, Document Icons should be stored in hive 16: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\IMAGES` .

[image]

Try to browse the following address to check if the pdf icon exists:

```
http://site_name/_layouts/images/icpdf.png
```

If not, please copy the PDF icon image to the appropriate folder in the SharePoint hive.

Then navigate to this location and find **DocIcon.xml**: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\XML`

Add the pdf icon mapping in this file then run IISRESET, reboot the server:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="icpdf.png" OpenControl=""/>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, However I've checked again the given instructions, in my server, it has the folder 16 and  48_icpdf.png and DOCICON.xml also configured as you mentioned. I've restarted the server and did IISRESET. But still the icons are not loaded. What else I'm missing . Please help me

Comment: Try to backup the pdf icon, delete the existing one and add again with above steps.

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks for replying.  your idea is working for me now, but it works only in chrome and firefox, but not in Internet explorer. Did i missing anything for IE especially ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no specific settings for IE browser, what's the version of IE? Update IE to the latest version to check the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when I am using a .JPG file for the icon, it will display properly in Chrome and Edge, but not in IE. If I change it to a .GIF, then it will display in IE (11). In other words, if I open a new tab, http://site/_layouts/images/pdf.jpg displays a black 'X', but http://site/_layouts/images/pdf.gif displays the pdf icon. My problem is that even after updating the DOCICON.XML file and placing the .GIF in the IMAGES folder, the XSLT web parts are still trying to GET the .JPG file, while the actual document libraries themselves are GET-ing and showing the .GIF file. I think the web parts are just broken.